# Facebook SDK and Swift 2.0 - Problems with handling accessToken

Tags: ios

my name is Vincent and I need your help !

(My code is not exhaustive)
No problem to login or logout with the Facebook SDK ... BUT
When I start my app, no access token and when i click on the Login button, it prints me an accessToken, then I logout.

How to get the accessToken when the app starts ?

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        getUserStatuts()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK -> Facebook Connect

    func loginToFacebook() {
        if let fbToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {
            print("Acces token : \(fbToken)")
            loginManager.logOut()
            print("Logout")
        } else {
            print("Login")
            loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(publishPermissions, fromViewController: nil, handler: {
                (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    self.getUserData()
                } else {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func getUserData() {
        let readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_birthday"]
        let parameters = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, name, birthday, picture.type(large)"]
        let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters)
        request.startWithCompletionHandler({
            (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                // display info
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the login function you want to implement the 
`let fbLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
fblogin.logout()`

the `fblogin.logout()` must be implemented before   `fbLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (facebookResult, facebookError) in
            if facebookError != nil {` ` to clear any access tokens from previous login.